# Can a PyMC3 trace be loaded and values accessed without the original model in memory?

Tags: python, pymc3

I'm still learning the basics of working with PyMC3 so hopefully this isn't too painfully obvious in the documentation already. The basic idea is that I have put together my model, sampled it a bunch to build up my posterior distribution and saved the chains. If I follow the suggestion of the [Backends](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/api/backends.html#loading-a-saved-backend) page to load the chains like `trace = pm.backends.text.load('test_txt')` then I get `TypeError: No context on context stack`. What I'd expect is that I'd be able to point the `text.load` method at the saved database and I would get back numpy arrays with all the trace values, i.e. the database would contain all the information needed to access the chain values.

A little hunting and the only example of loading a trace in PyMC3 I could find was [here](http://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663-2016/16C_PyMC3.html#Saving-traces), and that shows the same model variable being used to load the trace as was used to create it. If I wanted to have a script to run my chains and a separate script to load and analyze the traces it appears the only way is to have the model initialized with the same commands in both files. That sounds prone to creating inconsistencies between the files however since I would have to keep the models identical manually.

Here's an example taken from the PyMC getting started page where I save the chain. I saved the following code in a short script.

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
from scipy import optimize

# Initialize random number generator
np.random.seed(123)

# True parameter values
alpha, sigma = 1, 1
beta = [1, 2.5]

# Size of dataset
size = 100

# Predictor variable
X1 = np.random.randn(size)
X2 = np.random.randn(size) * 0.2

# Simulate outcome variable
Y = alpha + beta[0]*X1 + beta[1]*X2 + np.random.randn(size)*sigma

basic_model = pm.Model()

with basic_model:
    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=10)
    beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, sd=10, shape=2)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', sd=1)

    # Expected value of outcome
    mu = alpha + beta[0]*X1 + beta[1]*X2

    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    Y_obs = pm.Normal('Y_obs', mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=Y)

    # obtain starting values via MAP
    start = pm.find_MAP(fmin=optimize.fmin_powell)

    # instantiate sampler
    step = pm.Slice(vars=[sigma])

    # instantiate database
    db = pm.backends.Text('so_save')

    # draw 5000 posterior samples
    trace = pm.sample(5000, step=step, start=start, trace=db)
```

Then running these next lines (at the Python CLI or in a separate script) gives

```
trace = pm.backends.text.load('so_save')
# TypeError: No context on context stack

trace = pm.backends.text.load('so_save', model=pm.Model())
print trace
print trace.varnames
# <MultiTrace: 1 chains, 5000 iterations, 0 variables>
# []

# run same first 36 lines from the big code block above
trace = pm.backends.text.load('so_save', model=basic_model)
print trace
print trace.varnames
# <MultiTrace: 1 chains, 5000 iterations, 4 variables>
# ['alpha', 'beta', 'sigma_log_', 'sigma']
```

For a little more motivation/context, I'm experimenting with modelling the same data in a couple slightly different ways. I would like to have nice long chains for each model on disk that I only have to generate once. Then I can play around with comparing them down the line as I think of ways I want to analyze the traces.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short answer:

Use this to save a trace

```
import pickle # python3
import cPickle as pickle # python 2

with open('my_model.pkl', 'wb') as buff:
    pickle.dump({'model': basic_model, 'trace': trace}, buff)
```

and then this to reload:

```
with open('my_model.pkl', 'rb') as buff:
    data = pickle.load(buff)  

basic_model, trace = data['model'], data['trace']
```

Long answer:

There has been some discussion over [deprecating the backends](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/2189) -- they were useful in the context of storing traces that would need to run for a long time, and could outrun the memory.  Using a persistent backend could then recover the work that had already been done.  Hamiltonian samplers are much more efficient, so shorter traces suffice, and so the on-disk backends have not received much dev time since ~2016.

There is some danger to loading untrusted pickle files (not a problem if you are running things locally), and it is becoming a priority to rethink persistence for PyMC3, but the above should work for now.

Comment: Do you mean persistence needs to be revisited for the PyMC3 project or Python pickling?

Answer (score 0):

To save and reload a trace in pymc3, you can use the methods: `pymc3.save_trace()` and `pymc3.load_trace()`. Alternatively, you can also use "pickle".